Need help adding JSON code to existing code (Sharepoint List in gallery view)
Ok, very new to JSON and coding Sharepoint Lists. I found a great tutorial on how to generate a list and 'transform' it into a beautiful gallery card view .
link in case above didn't work: https://www.flickr.com/photos/201486420@N06/54006414661/in/dateposted-public/
This is what I am trying to do/add:

link in case above didn't work: https://www.flickr.com/photos/201486420@N06/54006644383/in/dateposted-public/
Where the highlighted area is, I do not like the way the date is formatted. I will remove that, but would like it replaced with a simple text column titled 'Date'.
Also where the highlighted area is I would like to add another text field title 'Length'.
Now I know for both of these I need to add columns. But where I am stuck is what would the JSON code be to add those to my existing code so that the column headers for those two new columns appear and none other?
The area that has the description for the training, the basic text that says 'Refresher for Dealogic', where in the code can I change the background so it's light grey or blue? And not centered... I have tried everything!
My code - so far - is below. THANK YOU!!!
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 400,
  "width": 280,
  "debugMode": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralLight"
    },
    "style": {
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      "width": "100%",
      "border-width": "2px",
      "box-shadow": "0px 1.6px 3.6px 0 #00000024, 0px 0.3px 0.9px 0 #00000024",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "padding": "0 0 0 0px",
      "margin-bottom": "2px",
      "display": "flex",
      "flex-direction": "column"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontSize-s"
        },
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "line-height": "1.5em",
          "padding": "4px",
          "padding-left": "16px",
          "background-color": "=if([$Track] =='Module 1', '#0fc373', if([$Track] =='Module 2', '#ff8c0a',  if([$Track] =='Module 3', '#af78d2' '#0082f0')))",
          "color": "white",
          "font-size": "13.5px"
        },
        "txtContent": "[$Track]"
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {},
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "flex": "0px 1px 1px",
          "display": "flex",
          "align-items": "center"
        }, 
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
              "src": "[$Image.serverRelativeUrl]"
            },
            "style": {
              "float": "left",
              "width": "100%"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "flex": "0 0 0px",
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "flex-direction": "column"
        }, 
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex": "0 0 0px",
              "box-sizing": "border-box",
              "padding": "10px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-xl"
                },
                "style": {
                  "border": "0",
                  "padding": "4px",
                  "color": "white",
                  "position": "absolute",
                  "left": "10px",
                  "top": "40px",
                  "background-color": "transparent",
                  "cursor": "pointer"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Session]",
                "customRowAction": {
                  "action": "defaultClick"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-m"
                },
                "style": {
                  "line-height": "1.5em",
                  "margin-bottom": "8px",
                  "padding-top": "6px"
                },
                "customCardProps": {
                  "openOnEvent": "hover",
                  "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
                  "isBeakVisible": true,
                  "beakStyle": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#3c3c3c"
                  },
                  "formatter": {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                      "color": "white",
                      "background-color": "#3c3c3c",
                      "width": "300px",
                      "padding": "10px"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$About]"
                  }
                },
                "txtContent": "=if(indexOf([$About] + '|', '|' ) > 180, substring([$About], 0, 180) + '...', [$About])"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-row-listPadding"
                },
                "style": {
                  "position": "absolute",
                  "left": "10px",
                  "top": "320px",
                  "font-size": "10px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Age]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "background-color": "white",
                  "border-radius": "10%",
                  "position": "absolute",
                  "left": "12px",
                  "top": "165px",
                  "display": "flex",
                  "flex-direction": "row"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "forEach": "choiceIterator in [$Tool]",
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-white ms-fontSize-xl",
                      "title": "=[$choiceIterator]",
                      "iconName": "=if([$choiceIterator] == 'Teams', 'TeamsLogo' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Forms', 'OfficeFormsLogo' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'SharePoint', 'SharepointLogo' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Whiteboard', 'WhiteboardApp32' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Stream', 'StreamLogo' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Office', 'OfficeLogo' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Computer', 'System' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'PowerApps', 'PowerApps' ,  if([$choiceIterator] == 'Power Automate', 'MicrosoftFlowLogo' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Mobile', 'CellPhone' , if([$choiceIterator] == 'Outlook', 'OutlookLogo' ,  if([$choiceIterator] == 'Planner', 'PlannerLogo' ,  if([$choiceIterator] == 'To-Do' ,'ToDoLogoInverse', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Security' , 'LaptopSecure', 'SharePointLogo')))))))))"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "background-color": "white",
                      "border-radius": "100%",
                      "width": "25px",
                      "height": "20px",
                      "text-align": "center",
                      "padding": "2px",
                      "margin": "1px",
                      "color": "=if([$choiceIterator] == 'Teams', '#6264a7',  if([$choiceIterator] == 'SharePoint', '#036C70', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Forms', '#007F70', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Outlook', '#0078D4', if([$choiceIterator]== 'Stream',  '#BC1948', if([$choiceIterator] == 'PowerApps', '#752875', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Mobile', '#0E41B1', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Computer', '#73276C', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Power BI', '#EDBF2C', if([$choiceIterator] == 'Whiteboard', '#1E8EE5', if([$choiceIterator] == 'To-Do' , '#175BBD', '#252423' )))))))))"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-bgColor-transparent sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight"
            },
            "style": {
              "position": "absolute",
              "right": "8px",
              "top": "150px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "flex"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "p",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "sp-card-userEmptyText"
                        },
                        "txtContent": "=if(length([$Responsible]) == 0, '–', '')"
                      },
                      {
                        "forEach": "personIterator in [$Responsible]",
                        "elmType": "a",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'sp-card-userContainer', 'sp-card-userContainer sp-card-keyboard-focusable')"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'none', '')"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "img",
                            "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                            "attributes": {
                              "src": "=getUserImage([$personIterator.email], 'S')",
                              "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                              "class": "sp-card-userThumbnail"
                            },
                            "style": {
                              "display": "=if(length([$Responsible]) > 5 && loopIndex('personIterator') >= 4, 'none', '')",
                              "border-radius": "50%",
                              "padding": "-1px"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-userOthers"
                            },
                            "style": {
                              "display": "=if(length([$Responsible]) > 5 && loopIndex('personIterator') == 4, '', 'none')",
                              "border-radius": "50%"
                            },
                            "customCardProps": {
                              "formatter": {
                                "elmType": "div",
                                "attributes": {
                                  "class": "sp-card-personCallout"
                                },
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "forEach": "personIterator in [$Responsible]",
                                    "elmType": "div",
                                    "attributes": {
                                      "class": "sp-card-userContainer sp-card-userCustomCard"
                                    },
                                    "style": {
                                      "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') < 4, 'none', '')",
                                      "border-radius": "50%"
                                    },
                                    "children": [
                                      {
                                        "elmType": "img",
                                        "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                                        "attributes": {
                                          "src": "=getUserImage([$personIterator.email], 'S')",
                                          "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                                          "class": "sp-card-userThumbnail"
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              "openOnEvent": "hover"
                            },
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "elmType": "span",
                                "txtContent": "='+' + toString(length([$Responsible]) - (4))"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
              "flex": "0px 10px 0px",
              "display": "flex",
              "flex-direction": "row"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "defaultClick"
                    },
                  "style": {
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "left": "0px",
                      "top": "350px",
                      "width": "40px",
                      "margin-left": "10px",
                      "display": "span",
                      "background-color": "transparent",
                      "border-radius": "4px"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "title": "Video",
                      "class": "sp-row-button sp-row-button ms-bgColor-purpleDark--hover ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-black"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "span",
                        "style": {
                          "color": "#0082f0",
                          "align-content": "left",
                          "justify-content": "left",
                          "padding": "4px",
                          "white-space": "normal"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "iconName": "Video",
                          "class": "ms-font-xl"
                        }
},
                         
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "share"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "left": "70px",
                      "top": "350px",
                      "width": "40px",
                      "margin-left": "10px",
                      "display": "span",
                      "background-color": "transparent",
                      "border-radius": "4px"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "title": "Share it",
                      "class": "sp-row-button sp-row-button ms-bgColor-purpleDark--hover ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-black"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "span",
                        "style": {
                          "color": "#0082f0",
                          "align-content": "left",
                          "justify-content": "left",
                          "padding": "4px",
                          "white-space": "normal"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "iconName": "Share",
                          "class": "ms-font-xl"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "defaultClick"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "position": "absolute",
                      "left": "35px",
                      "top": "348px",
                      "width": "40px",
                      "margin-left": "10px",
                      "display": "span",
                      "background-color": "transparent",
                      "border-radius": "4px"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "title": "PowerPoint Presentation",
                      "class": "sp-row-button sp-row-button ms-bgColor-purpleDark--hover ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-black",
                      "href": "[$Learning]",
                      "target": "_blank"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "span",
                        "style": {
                          "color": "#0082f0",
                          "align-content": "center",
                          "padding": "6px",
                          "padding-left": "12px",
                          "white-space": "normal"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "iconName": "PowerPointDocument",
                          "class": "ms-font-xl"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
]
}
}

